# Transparent background in NoiseInk (Java)

Tags: java, video, transparency, kinect, processing

A friend is making an art piece using NoiseInk https://github.com/trentbrooks/Noise-Ink and would like the background to be transparent instead of black. Ideally he would have this Java app running over a video (hence the transparency). So how could he play a video as the background, or at the very least make the background transparent? I have tried everything I could think of!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The catch is your friend is not clearing the screen, but adding a transparent rectangle to get a trails effect in the [easyFade()](https://github.com/trentbrooks/Noise-Ink/blob/master/NoiseInk/NoiseInk.pde#L115) function:

```
void easyFade()
{
  fill(bgColor,overlayAlpha);
  noStroke();
  rect(0,0,width,height);//fade background
}
```

The same can be done with images, but slightly different: simply use the [tint()](http://processing.org/reference/tint_.html) function to add transparency to your background video. Just for testing purposes, say you have an image to test this with (test.png), you can try something like this:

```
PImage bg;
void setup(){
  size(240,240);noStroke();
  bg = loadImage("test.png");
}
void draw(){
  easyFade();
  fill(255);
  ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,10,10);
}
void easyFade()
{
  tint(255,10);
  image(bg,0,0);
}
```

In your case the video will either be a loaded [Movie](http://processing.org/reference/libraries/video/Movie.html) or a live [Capture](http://processing.org/reference/libraries/video/Capture.html) but the above would still work, since both extend PImage (and you render them to screen with the `image()` call).

**UPDATE**

One issue with this approach though is the fade will affect the background video as well.
To keep things separated, you can use another 'layer' using [PGraphics](http://processing.org/reference/PGraphics.html):

```
import processing.video.*;

PGraphics gfx;
Capture video;
int w = 640;
int h = 480;
void setup() {
  size(w, h);
  video = new Capture(this, w, h,30);
  video.start();
  gfx = createGraphics(w, h);
  gfx.beginDraw();
  gfx.background(0);
  gfx.endDraw();
//  println(Capture.list());
}
void draw(){
  image(video,0,0);
  pushStyle();
  tint(255,127);//tint just the rendered graphics as transparent to see the video beneath
  image(gfx,0,0);
  popStyle();
  //draw your awesome optical flow graphics here
  gfx.beginDraw();
  gfx.fill(0,10);//same as easyFade() draw transparent bg
  gfx.rect(0,0,width,height);
  gfx.fill(255);
  gfx.ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,10,10);
  gfx.endDraw();
}
void captureEvent(Capture c) {
  c.read();
}
```

Again, this would display the graphics faded.
A variation of this would be blending the graphics layer, using the [blend()](http://processing.org/reference/blend_.html) function.
Given that normally the graphics background  is dark and you want to overlay the bright graphics, you can use a blend mode like ADD or SCREEN which would make 'background'/dark areas transparent:

```
import processing.video.*;

PGraphics gfx;
Capture video;
int w = 640;
int h = 480;
void setup() {
  size(w, h);
  video = new Capture(this, w, h,30);
  video.start();
  gfx = createGraphics(w, h);
  gfx.beginDraw();
  gfx.background(0);
  gfx.endDraw();
//  println(Capture.list());
}
void draw(){
  image(video,0,0);
  blend(gfx,0,0,w,h,0,0,w,h,SCREEN);//blend the rendered graphics on top of the video using SCREEN mode
  //draw your awesome optical flow graphics here
  gfx.beginDraw();
  gfx.fill(0,10);//same as easyFade() draw transparent bg
  gfx.rect(0,0,width,height);
  gfx.fill(255);
  gfx.ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,10,10);
  gfx.endDraw();
}
void captureEvent(Capture c) {
  c.read();
}
```

Have fun playing with these! :)

Comment: Well I seem to have **something** working! I'll keep poking around but I managed to get a video playing in the background, thank you very much for your help. By the way, NoiseInk isn't made by my friend - he's just using it.

Comment: Regarding your friend, I misunderstood (I assumed if he coded that he would've figured this one out :P). Check out my updated answer, I've added a couple of extra approaches. Feel free to vote as you see fit ;)

Comment: Thanks, I'm having a play around, almost there now! Your help was amazing, thank you again. I can't vote up as I don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: My friend's now getting this error https://docs.google.com/document/d/1alB3W0dvidziDxSEqfIcjoTm_ATjohr8RppKzN4hu68/edit - any idea what would be causing it? Using the code above

Comment: That looks like an OSX crash report and to be honest I'm very good at deciphering that. This caught my attention: `Current thread (00000000053fa000):  JavaThread "Thread-3" [_thread_in_native, id=-1307250688, stack(00000000b204f000,00000000b214f000)]
Stack: [00000000b204f000,00000000b214f000]
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  quicktime.qd.Pict.GetMoviePict(II)I+0
J  processing.video.Movie.read()V
j  processing.video.Movie.run()V+46
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
`. This might be a wild guess, but check if the path to the movie your loading/reading is correct...

Comment: ...notice that on osx the sketch path and data paths might differe a bit in an exported app (as the actual executable in within the .app/Contents/MacOS folder, etc.). Try playing with the [sketchPath()](http://processing.org/reference/javadoc/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#sketchPath(java.lang.String)) or [dataPath()](http://processing.org/reference/javadoc/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#dataPath(java.lang.String)) (or if the app isn't going to run on any other computer than your own using an absolute path). And see if that's the culprit. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help but it does run, after a random amount of time (5 mins, 15 mins etc) it will crash. So it finds the videos, it's just that it crashes after a random period of time no matter what video

Comment: Perhaps the app is running out of memory or the kinect driver having a fit ? I find it hard to tell exactly what the issue is. Can you try using `jvisualvm` and take a memory snapshot at the start of the app, after everything is initialized, then one 5 minutes later (ideally before  crash) ? Perhaps by peaking at how memory allocation changes, if there's leak somewhere that is the cause of the crash, you should be able to compare the two memory snapshots and find the issue. Separately Could you run an exported application that simply deals with the kinect part nothing else ? ...

Comment: ...see if that crashes. A tedious approach I can think of is commenting out most of the functionalities that are used in the draw() loop, then adding one at a time, testing the exported app to see if it crashes/spikes in memory/cpu usage, etc.

Comment: Thanks again :) We now think it's a memory fault for sure, segmentation fault 11 also comes up

Comment: Just had another look at the NoiseInk original and it looks pretty tight (in terms of memory allocations for images/particles/etc.) so start looking at what you added extra and make sure you don't constantly keep creating new objects(images/particles) all the time in your code additions. Depending on what version of java you have on osx you might have `jvisualvm` already and it should make it easier to find the functions that take longest to execute and the bigger memory footprints. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I'll use that, StackOverflow is telling me off for "extended discussions" in the comments so I'll leave it here, use jvisualvm and work from there. Thanks again!